# Built-in SSH Terminal/Console in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ssh, terminal

Searched around in SO and Google but didn't find anything useful.
What would be the easiest way to implement an SSH console inside my iOS app ?

There are many apps doing this already like [SSH Terminal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ssh-terminal/id369875227?mt=8) or [Diet Coda](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diet-coda/id500906297?mt=8), but I wondered if there's an open source component or anything of such nature that I can just drop in my project, and if not - any resources that you can point me at to build my own implementation would be highly appreciated.

**Update:** So far I only found one solution from Chilkat, but unfortunately it costs a whooping $150 for a single developer license... Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Diet Coda is most likely using the engine from [prompt](http://panic.com/prompt), made by the same company.

Comment: As interesting as it is (it really is :P) , It isn't a solution :( I found a library called libssh2-for-iOS but it seems outdated, crashes often and doesnt seem to support private keys

Comment: I know, sorry... since it's a very specific thing, I doubt there's an open-source library for it.

Comment: As I said there's libssh for iOS but it doesn't function as well as I'd expect ;

Comment: Thank you anyways for trying to assist! :)

Comment: yep, just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9355937/840973) which actually suggests libssh, voting to close.

Comment: I dont think this should be closed since I'm looking for an iOS native library (Objective C) , and not C++.

Comment: Prompt and Diet Coda use libssh2 under the hood. It's worked great for us so far!

Comment: Thanks Dave! Any resources I could read on using it with ObjC?